# Can we set Linux default XTERM to VT100

Tags: linux, terminal, centos, vt100

i am using centos
i want to use  default TERM = vt100

i tried to set in the .bashrc, .bash_profile,.profile
export $TERM=VT100

but  when trying to ssh into device
echo $TERM returns xterm-color

how we can set default TERM=vt100

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SetEnv` in your SSH config (probably ~/.ssh/config):

```
Host server_ip_address
    SetEnv TERM=VT100
```